# trade life cycle of a bond from proposal to settlement

Tags: pricing

How is the trade life cycle of a bond from proposal to settlement, in terms of who does what at a buy-side firm as a part of this process (e.g. at an Asset Manager, Hedge Fund, etc) different from the sell side

Comment: Do you meant the entire process of issuing bonds? That is in my opinion off topic because that is way to broad. There are several ways this can be done and numerous steps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.